# Is there a way to make a single loop for two different variables?

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to make a single loop for two variables. I have a "p1" (player 1) and a "p2". Both have the particularity to use the same loop to have a certain number of spaces. Is there a solution to make a single loop instead of creating two? Here is the loop in question for the player one:

```
    for (string::size_type i = 1; i < (SIZE - p1.name.length()) / 2; i++) {
   
        cout << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you separate the initialization and updates with commas (,) and convert the condition to a compound one.

```
for (string::size_type i = 1, j = 1; i < (SIZE - p1.name.length()) / 2 && j < (SIZE - p2.name.length()) / 2; i++, j++) {
   
        cout << " ";
}
```

Comment: The decl+init statement in a for-loop can declare+init multiple vars, but only one *specified* type. can appear. E.g. `for (string::size_type i = 1, string::size_type j = 1;` is *not* valid; `for (string::size_type i = 1, j = 1;` *is* valid.

Comment: Haha not wrong I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks friend

Comment: @WhozCraig not saying you should, but you could use structured binding: `for ( auto [a, b] = std::tuple{std::size_t(0), SomeType()}; …`